# Python Multithreading : Wait for multiple threads to execute another thread

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, python-multithreading

```
for i in range (5):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=some_fun,args=("thread : {}".format(i), fun_args))
        thread.start()
        
thread6 = threading.Thread(target=some_fun,args=("thread : 6", fun_args))
thread6.start()
thread7 = threading.Thread(target=some_fun,args=("thread : 7", fun_args))
thread7.start()
```

Here I am creating 5 threads dynamically(1 to 5) and two threads(6 and 7) manually which will execute same function(some_fun) with different arguments.

**Problem** : I want to execute Thread 6 just after Thread 1 and Thread 2 got executed, Thread 7 to execute just after Thread 4. Thread 6 not necessarily to wait for Thread 3, 4, 5 and 7 for completion and similarly Thread 7 will not wait for other threads except thread 4. There can be many dependencies of threads on another thread like this.

How can I achieve this? Please help

Comment: It sounds like you need additional threads which each take a list of threads to join and a (list of) thread(s) to start.

Comment: I think a simple and straightforward way for you to coordinate these threads is by using a thread-safe message queue

Comment: Hi,  foo_job = queue.enqueue(foo)
bar_job = queue.enqueue(bar)
baz_job = queue.enqueue(baz, depends_on=[foo_job, bar_job])  --https://python-rq.org/docs/  --code is under Job dependencies head